using "regex_search" API for regex matching is not matching for non-English regex and special character hyphen("-") in C++
I am using regex_search API for regex matching in c++ but it is failing if regex is Japanese or contains hyphen ("-") whereas if I use normal English regex, it works fine.
Working Eample-
FileName - L"SampleWord.docx"
regex - L"\\bSampleWord\\b"
Non-Working examples can be seen below.
Please suggest why I am getting this behavior.
Example1- Japanese
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    wstring fileNameJapanese = L"料監査.txt";
    std::wstring policyWordJapanase = L"\\b料監査\\b";

    std::wregex regexJapanse(policyWordJapanase, std::wregex::icase);
    if (regex_search(fileNameJapanese, regexJapanse))
    {
        wcout << "matched" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        wcout << "not matched" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

Output
not matched

Example 2 - Hyphen
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    wstring fileName1 = L"AENL- Int'l Passport- Sample.docx";
    wstring fileName2 = L"AENL- Int'l Passport-Sample.docx";
    wstring fileName3 = L"AENL- Int'l Passport-.docx";
    std::wstring policyWord = L"\\bAENL- Int\u0027l Passport-\\b";

    std::wregex regex(policyWord, std::wregex::icase);
    if (regex_search(fileName1, regex))
    {
        wcout << fileName1 << " matched" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        wcout << fileName1 << " not matched" << endl;
    }

    if (regex_search(fileName2, regex))
    {
        wcout << fileName2 << " matched" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        wcout << fileName2 << " not matched" << endl;
    }

    if (regex_search(fileName3, regex))
    {
        wcout << fileName3 << " matched" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        wcout << fileName3 << " not matched" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

output
AENL- Int'l Passport- Sample.docx not matched
AENL- Int'l Passport-Sample.docx matched
AENL- Int'l Passport-.docx not matched


TLDR: Either do not use the default library and switch to either ICU/Boost (recommended), or use workarounds if they can yield expected results.

You need to set up global locale to make it work: https://godbolt.org/z/WEYf58Tf1
